# Pass parameters with EventEmitter

Tags: angular, eventemitter, angular2-directives

I have a directive to initializes a jQueryUI sortable on a DOM element. The jQueryUI sortable also has a set of callback events that trigger on certain actions. For example, when you [start](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-start) or [stop](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-stop) sorting elements.

I'd like to pass the return parameters from such an event through the `emit()` function, so I can actually see what happend in my callback function. I just haven't found a way to pass parameters through an `EventEmiiter`.

I currently have the following.

My directive:

```js
@Directive({
    selector: '[sortable]'
})
export class Sortable {
    @Output() stopSort = new EventEmitter();

    constructor(el: ElementRef) {
      console.log('directive');
        var options = {
          stop: (event, ui) => {
            this.stopSort.emit(); // How to pass the params event and ui...?
          }
        };

        $(el.nativeElement).sortable(options).disableSelection();
    }
}
```

And this is my `Component` that uses the event emiited by the directive:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  directives: [Sortable],
  providers: [],
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Event from jQueryUI to Component demo</h2>

      <ul id="sortable" sortable (stopSort)="stopSort(event, ui)">
        <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 1</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 2</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  `
})
export class App {
  constructor() {

  }

  stopSort(event, ui) { // How do I get the 'event' and 'ui' params here?
    console.log('STOP SORT!', event);
  }
}
```

How can I get the `event` and `ui` params in my `stopSort()` function?

Here is a demo of what I have so far: http://plnkr.co/edit/5ACcetgwWWgTsKs1kWrA?p=info

Comment: I'm not able to figure out what `ui` should be. Where does it come from? What should if refer to?

Answer (score 160, accepted):

EventEmitter supports one argument, which is passed as `$event` to your event handler.

Wrap your parameters in an event object when you pass it to `emit`:

```js
this.stopSort.emit({ event:event, ui: ui });
```

Then, when you handle the event, use `$event`:

```js
stopSort($event) { 
  alert('event param from Component: ' +$event.event);
  alert('ui param from Component: ' + $event.ui);
}
```

[Demo Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/yJXeRiJAMxfQV6vr4j0Q?p=preview)

Comment: Just a small remark when using ES6 {event: event, ui: ui} can be shortened to {event, ui}

Comment: Just a small remark since I fought with that for an hour: You HAVE TO name the property `$event` in your method. Otherwise you get an undefined.

Comment: Slightly off-topic but can anyone please explain about dollar($) sign? Why it's always use with EventEmiter parameter?

Answer (score 34):

pixelbits answer have changed a bit with final release. If you have multiple parameters, just pass it through as one object.

Child component:

```js
this.stopSort.emit({event,ui});

@Output() stopSort= new EventEmitter<any>();
```

Parent Component:

```js
hereIsHeight(value) {
        console.log("Height = " + value.event); 
        console.log("Title = " + value.ui); 
    }
```

HTML in parent component:

```js
<test-child1 (stopSort)="hereIsHeight($event)"></test-child1>
```

-- Also if you have values like:    (with the "this" in front)

```js
this.stopSort.emit({this.event,this.ui});
```

they will not work, you need to change them to something else and then pass through like:

```js
let val1 = this.event;
let val2 = this.ui;
this.stopSort.emit({val1,val2});
```

***Update: Read Colin B's answer below for a way to pass values with "this."**

Comment: note: in `<test-child1 (stopSort)="hereIsHeight($event)"></test-child1>` you must use parameter name `$event` else it seems not working

Answer (score 10):

I can't add a comment, but just wanted to point out from Alpha Bravo's answer that you can pass `this.event`, you just can't use property value shorthand:

```
this.stopSort.emit({ event : this.event, ui : this.ui });
```

---

Also note, if they are passed through the EventEmmiter as `this.stopSort.emit({ val1, val2 });` then they would be accessed in the parent as:

```
hereIsHeight(value) {
    console.log(`event = ${ value.val1 }`); 
    console.log(`ui = ${ value.val2 }`); 
}
```

So avoiding the shorthand might be preferable in this type of situation to keep naming consistent.

Answer (score 5):

Works like this in child:

```
@Output() myEvent: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter();
myFunc(value: boolean) {
    this.myEvent.emit(value);
}
```

Now you just have to grab the event in the parent!